# Can I call a custom function in an excel spreadsheet from the microsoft graph?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

In the Microsoft graph REST API docs, it shows [how to call a function from an excel sheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0#workbook-functions).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/book1.xlsx:/workbook/functions/pmt
content-type: Application/Json 
authorization: Bearer {access-token} 
workbook-session-id: {session-id}

{
    "rate": 4.5,
    "nper": 12,
    "pv": -1250
}
```

The example they use is `pmt`, which is a built in Excel function. It seems odd that the query needs to hit a specific excel file to do that, as the result from that function is totally independent from a specific workbook.

Is this a quirk of excel, that everything needs to hit a specific workbook, or is it possible to make this API hit a custom function?

I've tried to make a [custom function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f) in an .xlsm that's in my onedrive:

```
Function YO(name)
 YO = "yo " + name
End Function
```

Which works in the spreadsheet, but gives the following error from the API:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'yo'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-05-13T07:58:00",
            "request-id": "5ca7d80b-e326-4819-abf7-1928d08c599e",
            "client-request-id": "ab896375-ce1f-9ee2-2b08-2fa7d378f007"
        }
    }
}
```

This leaves me with these questions:

- If this *is* possible, how would I do it?
- If it's not possible, why does it need a specific workbook to run the function?

The real world use case I can see for this is: If I want to expose a calc that's in a spreadsheet to an external user as an API that doesn't need a developer to build the logic for an endpoint in a fancy way.